# Python modules importing

Tags: python, module, import

I have folder with such structure:

```
parent/
   ---__init__.py
   ---SomeClass.py
   ---Worker.py
```

First file (`__init__.py`) is empty.

Second file (`SomeClass.py`) content is following code:

```
class Test:
   pass
```

Third file (`Worker.py`):

```
import SomeClass
Test()
```

> ImportError: No module named SomeClass

What I do wrong?

Comment: For me it fails in a different way - it fails to resolve Test() symbol. And that's fine - you need to either use the fully qualified name 'SomeClass.Test()', or import it into the module's name space: 'from SomeClass import Test' and left the second line as is. This doesn't answer your original question, however. How are you spawning this code?

Comment: Where are you running the program from, and how (e.g. `import parent.Worker`)?

Comment: @sam-magura running from same directory.

Comment: you mean python Worker.py from within 'parent'? Or importing it from the directory one-level up, as Sam Magura suggested? Give us more details :)

Comment: @CodePainters, I think it is due to the version of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from . import SomeClass
```

but remember you'll have to

```
SomeClass.Text()
```

instead of just `Test()`

Comment: Well I messed up, you can use it in 2.x too.

Comment: relative imports are Python 2.6 and later

Comment: Ah, yes I only checked 2.7. Using 3.x really makes hard dealing with 2.x issues. Well that was my reason to chose 3 =)